# How to route all traffic through a VPN?

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp, pptpd

I executed an pppd command and i got the following output:

```
local  IP address 172.16.4.128
remote IP address 172.16.1.200
Committed PPP store
Committed PPP store
pptp_wait_input: Address added. previous interface setting (name: en0, address: 192.168.1.84), current interface setting (name: ppp0, family: PPP, address: 172.16.4.128, subnet: 255.255.0.0, destination: 172.16.1.200).
```

I tried to add a rule with `route add -net 172.16.1.200` without any success. I want to route all traffic into the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

You need, at least, this 2 routes:

```
DEFAULT via dev PPP_DEVICE
VPN_SERVER via LOCAL_NETWORK_GATEWAY
```

You can have this two routes with this commands:

```
ip route add VPN_SERVER via LOCAL_NETWORK_GATEWAY
ip route add default via PPP_DEVICE(ex: ppp0)
```

Probably you will need to remove the local default gateway route:

```
ip route del default via LOCAL_NETWORK_GATEWAY
```